# MSTest can not publish results. Says that platform and flavour are not right and they are

Tags: msbuild, mstest, publishing, trx

we are trying to execute unit tests with MSTest from command line and publishing the results at the TFS server. The problem is that MSTest is always returning:

`Publishing results of test run buildmachine@XXX-XXXXXXX 2010-12-16 11:39:13_Release_Any 
CPU to http://xxxx:8080/Build/v1.0/PublishTestResultsBuildService2.asmx...
.........................................................................................
Build 'xxx>xxx>x>x>x>xxxx>xxxx>x.x.x.xxx' does not include the specified 
configuration ('Release/Any CPU').`

The problem is that the specified configuration should exist. We've build with the next MSBuild settings:

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
  <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
  <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
```

Any idea? I'm starting to be fed up with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the build didn't succeeded and then MSTest couldn't publish the results. The error message could be better ...